# NSFontAttributeName's size is not applied to range in NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I'm setting a range in a string with a smaller font, approx half the original font, like so:

```
// string is "30:00.0"
func getTime(string:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:string)

    let smallFont = UIFont(name:SPConstants.FontName, size:SPConstants.FontSizeDashboardSmall)!
    let baselineOffset = bigLabel.font.capHeight - smallFont.capHeight
    let decimalRange:NSRange = (timeString as NSString).range(of: ".")
    let superscriptRange = NSRange(location:decimalRange.location, length:(timeString.characters.count - decimalRange.location))

    let attributes = [
      NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:baselineOffset,
      NSFontAttributeName:smallFont
      ] as [String : Any]

    attributedString.addAttributes(attributes, range:superscriptRange)
    // attributedString.setAttributes(attributes, range:superscriptRange)
    return attributedString
}
```

Here's what it looks like initially rendered:

[Attributed string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KHWr.png)

Here is what it should look like initially, however appears this way only after a user action triggers a layout pass:

[Attributed string after layout pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md2Tk.png)

Strangely the baseline attribute is applied immediately but the small font size is not. Then both attributes are applied after a layout pass.

a) Attributed string is created and assigned to UILabel attributedText, which is in the first image.

b) A button is tapped and label is reset with a new attributed string. The new string also has the initial value "30:00.0", which is the second image. The rendering is corrected at this point.

c) A timer starts and the value decrements 1/10 every 10th of a sec and updates the label. The rendering is also correct.

```
fileprivate lazy var bigLabel:UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel.newAutoLayout()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.font = UIFont(name:SPConstants.FontName, size:SPConstants.FontSizeDashboardBig)
    return label
  }()

. . .

bigLabel.attributedText = getTime(string:"30:00.0")
```

Any ideas how to resolve?

**UPDATE**

Narrowed it down to an extension, which is used to set the same Font globally.

```
extension UILabel {
    @objc public var substituteFontName : String {
        get {
            return self.font.fontName
        }
        set {
            var fontName = newValue
            self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: self.font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}
```

And in AppDelegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UILabel.appearance().substituteFontName = SPConstants.FontName
```

**UPDATE 2**

Realized the extension setter must be affecting it. To work around I create a subclass SPLabel and check the class type in the setter. Am getting the results needed.

```
fileprivate lazy var bigLabel:SPLabel = {

. . .

set {
    if !(self is SPLabel) {
        self.font = UIFont(name:newValue, size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this attributed string actually being used?

Comment: Added more info. Please see updated post